# trying to compile a c program but I am getting fatal error:/usr/include/rpc/misc/abstract_atomic.h

Tags: c, linux, rpc, kali-linux

I am trying to compile my programm. First I got the fatal error:rpc/rpc.h, tried some fixes and then fatal error:/usr/include/rpc/misc/abstract_atomic.h. Now I get fatal error: netconfig.h. I have no idea what to do. Can someone help?

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Test/Blatt4]
└─$ gcc -c rls_clnt.c rls_svc.c rls_xdr.c
In file included from /usr/include/rpc/rpc.h:38,
                 from rls.h:9,
                 from rls_clnt.c:7:
/usr/include/rpc/types.h:240:10: fatal error: netconfig.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
  240 | #include <netconfig.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/rpc/rpc.h:38,
                 from rls.h:9,
                 from rls_svc.c:6:
/usr/include/rpc/types.h:240:10: fatal error: netconfig.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
  240 | #include <netconfig.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/rpc/rpc.h:38,
                 from rls.h:9,
                 from rls_xdr.c:6:
/usr/include/rpc/types.h:240:10: fatal error: netconfig.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
  240 | #include <netconfig.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: check if file /usr/include/rpc/misc/abstract_atomic.h exists?

Comment: It says pretty clearly what the problem is. Also, Kali is a single-purpose pentest platform, not usually a platform that you compile software on. Are you able to do this on a fully fledged Linux distro? In that case: do. If not: figure out how to do it on a proper linux distro, not on Kali, which is [**not** meant for that (says Kali themselves)](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/).

Comment: well no^^ there is no directory called misc

Comment: All information should be in the question, and you should copy&paste text to the question and format it as a code block instead of showing a screenshot. You can [edit] your question by clicking on the gray word `Edit` below the question. (At least for your next question, as this one will probably get closed soon.)

Comment: @Bodo I did. better now?

Comment: @Traffix Yes, it is better, but anyway you will not get much help because Kali is a specialized distribution for experts, and your question leaves the impression that you are a beginner. See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/330217